Can I mitigate risk ESD to a sensitive device with small insulating panels?
I have an electrostatic-sensitive device held in an aluminum block. It has to be aluminum for temperature control. I recently destroyed said device by touching the aluminum block on a low-humidity day.
Can I mitigate the risk of future ESD by gluing little panels of rubber or placing electric tape onto the sides of the block, so I can handle it without touching the metal?
Or could a deposit of charge on these insulating panels still result in shock through a capacitive effect?

The device is a laser diode, it sits in an aluminum collimation tube (see photo). The block is a few centimeters on a side, it's for an external cavity diode laser. When connected to the control electronics, wires come out the back of the collimation tube, and a thermoelectric cooler sits underneath the block. The screw lets me connect a chassis grounding wire to the block. 

Why not use the full range of existing static control measures?  Wrist straps and conductive mats are cheap.

My question was about whether insulating panels would provide additional protection.  I will use my wrsit straps going forward. (I used them to install the laser diode, but wrongly thought I was safe given that the pins on the laser diode don't touch the aluminum block).

ESD stands for Electrostatic Discharge. What's a "device", what pin/signal of the "device" is connected to the heat sink, if any? What of this is grounded, if anything? The usual counter-measure against ESD is to ground everything down appropriately. Adding more non-conductive material like rubber might have the opposite effect. Can you share pictures or schematics?

If the pins are floating, their capacitance to the case will easily store ESD voltage causing failure. Always use anti-static or static dissipative techniques even after the laser is connected to circuitry.

No you can't use insulation for ESD control in reasonable ways. ESD can go through insulation if strong enough and through many millimeters. In addition the device can still 'see' electric fields as insulators do not block those (think capacitance, capacitors are two conductors with an insulator or dielectric in between).
The best way is shield the device and/or ground it.
